# Where to import Ktor Plugin "install" from

Tags: ktor

I just created a new Ktor project, but following the docs, I am unsure where to import Plugin "install" function.

```
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import io.netty.handler.codec.DefaultHeaders

fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "0.0.0.0") {
        install(DefaultHeaders)
        install(CallLogging)
        install(Koin) {
            slf4jLogger()
            modules(helloAppModule)
        }
        configurePlugins()
        configureRouting()
    }.start(wait = true)
}
```

My IDE has several suggestions, none of which seem to resolve correctly. I am using Ktor version 2.0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have incorrect [Default headers](https://ktor.io/docs/default-headers.html) import.

1. Make sure you have it as dependency:

   ```
   implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-default-headers:$ktor_version")
   ```
2. Replace

   ```
   import io.netty.handler.codec.DefaultHeaders
   ```

   with

   ```
   import io.ktor.server.plugins.defaultheaders.*
   ```
3. IDE should suggest you the following import for `install`:

   ```
   import io.ktor.server.application.*
   ```